# Difference between $T \colon V \to W $ and $ T \colon V \to V $ for $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

My professor proved rank-nullity theorem, and after that, he gave two examples for the transformations $T \colon V \to W $ and $ T \colon V \to V $ with $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$. He said something about isomorphism, but I couldn't get that.

Comment: $V\cong W\iff \dim V=\dim W$. "$\cong$" is an equivalence relation. $\dim V\cong\dim W\color{red}{\not\equiv} V=W$. And of course  $\exists T\in\mathcal(V,W)\implies V$ and $W$ are over the same field $\Bbb F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your professor said is that the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic.

Since this is your first linear algebra class, you are only dealing with finite-dimensional vector spaces. It turns out that if $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$, then there is in fact an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$.

This has nothing to do with the rank-nullity theorem *per se*. Since algebraic structures are sometimes only considered up to isomophism, your professor might have remarked "This is in fact the same example because $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic" or something along these lines.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no difference between vector spaces V and W? Can we write V = W?

Comment: No $V$ and $W$ are not equal, but they have identical vector space structures. For another example, the linear orderings $1<2<3$ and $5<7<9$ are not equal (two different sets of numbers) but are isomorphic as ordered sets by the map $f(n)=2n+3$.

Comment: No, $V$ and $W$ are different as sets. For example $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ consists of triples of real numbers and $W=\{p=a_2X^2+a_1X+a_0 \ | \ a_0, a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}$ consists of all polynomials with real coefficients and degree $\leq 2$. These are both vector spaces (verify the axioms!) and there is a nice correspondence between them: eg $(88, 0, 1)+(1,1,1)=(89,1,2)$ and $(88X^2+1)+(X^2+X+1)=89X^2+X+2$. In a sense, this is the same vector space and we formally say that there is an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$, writing $V \cong W$.